# What foreign key should I store from users table or clients table?

Tags: foreign-key

Let's say I have a table called `users` that contains basic user information like email and password and I also have a table named `clients`.

A client is a type of user, so that it will have a field that will hold the id of the corresponding user from table `users`, a field like `user_id`.

Now le'ts say there are tables that are specific to the client and then there will be the need to store the id of the client, like so:

Users table:

| id | Email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user1@email.com |
| 2 | user2@email.com |

Clients table:

| id | Name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 | 1 |
| 2 | User 2 | 2 |

Courses table:

| id | Name | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Course 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Course 2 | 2 |

Now what I really don't know is that what id should I save in Courses table.

Should I save the `client_id` from clients table or should I save the user id from users table as client id.

I really dont know because a client is a type of user and only a client can buy a course, not all types of users, on the other hand, a client doesn't exist without a user what's really confusing is that if I use the user id instead of the client id then the field should be called "user_id"? But then it would be generic as only clients can have a course.

So what's the best approach:

1 -  Name the field `client_id` and add the id of the client from clients table and get the user related to that client afterwards (I'm inclined to this one).

2 -  Name the field `client_id` and store the id of the user from users table and get the associated client (This is a bit more confusing but could make sense hierarchically speaking since there's no client without a user).

3 -  Name the field `user_id` and store the id of the user from users table (this approach really breaks the semantic in my opnion since `user_id` could be any user but only user of type client could have a course).

**-----------------------------UPDATE-------------------------**

So I think my question wasn't clear so I will clarify.

What I want to know is that if there's any best practice on this topic because the way I store and retrieve data would impact directly the way I retrieve data in the app due to the relationships.

Now, In a real case scenario where I have 3 tables: table `users`, table `clients` and table `courses`.

The table `clients` only hold the fields that wouldn't fit in the `users` table considering that I will have more type of users that will be in other tables too, like `administradors` which is also a type of user.

Now, considering a client wouldn't exist wihout a user and considering only clients can make purchases to buy a course for example, which id should I store in `client_id` in the `courses` table, the id from the table `clients` or the id from the table `users`.

For example only clients can buy products but a client (`clients` table) belongs to a user (`users` table). In table, say `purchased_products` that contains a field named `client_id`, should I have the id of client from table `clients` or the id of the user from table `users`?

Both make sense to me and I would be able to retrieve the data regardless what I really want to know is what makes more sense here:

1 - If I store the id from table `clients` in `courses.client_id`, I would retrieve the user like this: `$client->user` which hierarchically doesn't make sense since a user comes before a client and not the other way around but at least it would be the id of the table `client` stored in `courses.client_id`.

2 -  If I store the id of the table `users` in `courses.client_id`, I would retrieve data in a way that makes more sense like `$user->client but I fell like the name of the field should not be` courses.client_id`but rather`courses.user_id` but then it would also be bad because not all users can buy a course so might seem misleading.

In the first example `$client` contains all informatin related to the table `clients` and $client->user`would access all information related to the table`users` for that client.

In the second example `$user` contains all informatin related to the table `users` and $user->client`would access all information related to the table`clients` for that user.

Again it's more of a semantic question to make things more organized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... only a client can buy a course ...

Bingo!

There you have a Business Rule that states that the relationship is between [Purchased_]Course and *Client*, not [Purchased_]Course and *User*.  So you would store the Client's key in the Purchased_Course table.

And *yes*; I *have* added another table here.

Remember that a Course can exist in its own right, without anyone purchasing it, so that needs a table *of its own*.  The relationship between the Course and the Client *when they purchase it* needs a third table.

```
select * 
from Clients ; 

+----+--------+---------+
| id | Name   | user_id |
+----+--------+---------+
| 66 | User 1 |       1 |
| 77 | User 2 |       2 |
+----+--------+---------+

select * 
from Courses ; 

+-----+----------+
| id  | Name     | 
+-----+----------+
| 888 | Course 1 |
| 999 | Course 2 |
+-----+----------+

select * 
from Purchased_Courses ; 

+-----------+-----------+
| course_id | client_id | 
+-----------+-----------+
|       888 |        66 |
|       999 |        77 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I should store the client's id from `Clients` table in `Purchased_Courses` even if a client can't exist without a user, right? So I would retrieve the user based on the client's id like so: `client->user` ...yeah I get it but somehow doesn't make sense to me, hierarchically speaking, since the user comes first. Haha but anyway, thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, User "underpins" Client and a Client cannot exist without a User.  BUT you could have a User that /isn't/ a Client (and therefore, cannot purchase courses) but can do "other stuff" within the Application.  Model the Business Rules as far as you can.